# Update Input with select in CakePHP and FullCalendar

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar

Hey all,
I'm making a booking calendar for a rental house and I'm trying to make a selectable calendar update two form fields after selection.  I want users to be able to drag across available days and populate the start and end date of my form.  This is what I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: "bookings/feed",
            selectable: true,
            unselectAuto: false,
            select: function(startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                **I just don't know what to put here to edit the inputs bolded below**

            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div style="width: 500px;"><div id="calendar"></div></div>
<div id="eventdata"></div>
<div id="form">
    <?php echo $form->create('Booking'); ?>
    **<?php echo $form->input('start', array( 'label' => 'Check In:', 'type' =>'text')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->input('end', array( 'label' => 'Check Out:', 'type' =>'text')); ?>**
    <?php echo $form->input('firstName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->input('lastName'); ?>

</div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The following passes the Start and End dates to the form.

```
 select: function(startDate, endDate) {
                $( '#BookingStart' ).val(startDate)
                $( '#BookingEnd' ).val(endDate)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question didn't paste correctly, but in general to change the input value in jQuery you can do `$( '#id_name' ).val( 'new value' )`. CakePHP assigns form field ids with the pattern *ModelField* so the ids you need should be "BookingStart" and "BookingEnd" (you can verify by looking at the HTML source). You can also give the fields any id you want with `'id' => 'foo'` option.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I pass the data in the FullCalendar to that jquery function?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with FullCalendar. I would guess startDate and endDate contain the dates you need? You'd need to format them into whatever you need, but I don't know in what format they start with.